# Keep the changes MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have this :

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE data SET ap = 1 WHERE id = $id" ;
$retval = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT ap,id FROM data WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$ap = $row['ap'];
$idd = $row['id'];
}        
}
```

and :

```
<div id="<?php if($ap == 1 and $idd == 1){echo:'s1p';}else{echo:'s1';}?>" class="boxabs">
</div> 
<div id="<?php if($ap == 1 and $idd == 2){echo:'s2p';}else{echo:'s2';}?>" class="boxabs">
</div>
<div id="<?php if($ap == 1 and $idd == 3){echo:'s3p';}else{echo:'s3';}?>" class="boxabs">
</div>
```

When i change the URL to localhost/bla/index.php?id=3, even tho div 1 has $ap == 1, only div 3 shows green (s1p=green div,sp=red div).
Also, when I remove the $idd == x , all of them become green.

MySQL (if you don't understand what I mean):

```
id|ap 
1 |1  
2 |2
3 |1
```

Comment: $ap will keep being overwritten i nthe while loop, you will need your html in there

Comment: @nogad how can I overcome this? I can't think of anything

Comment: output or create the html in the while loop, or assign the values in to an array to use latter

Comment: @nogad sorry, im new at MySQL, how do I assign the values in an array?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: `mysql_*` never works `mysqli_`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the sort of thing you are trying to achieve. (untested).

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE data SET ap = 1 WHERE id = $id" ;
    $retval = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT ap,id FROM data WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());

    // set a counter here
    $i=1;
?>

<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <div id="<?php if($row['ap'] == 1 and $row['idd'] == 1){echo:"s$ip";}else{echo:"s$i";}?>" class="boxabs"></div>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I can see the way you thought about it and I find it interesting but unfortunately this is not what i wanted , sorry